# ConfigData framework not compiling on upload to Apple Store

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, code-signing

I having some problem while uploading file to Apple Store. 
After i generate the file (archive) i try to upload to Apple Store. 
But i got a message:
[image]

This only happens when i upload to Apple Store.
I already try to generate file with AD Hoc, to upload to HockeyApp. This way, i don't have this problem.

An interest thing: When i remove this ConfigData.framework from Embedded Binaries, now i have another error during prepare to upload: "Code signing OmiseSDK.framework failed." Even remove those frameworks, when i compile project, any error appear. But after archive and prepare to upload file to Apple Store, i have those strange errors.

Could someone help?